# change navigation order between textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a master-details in windows form.

I created data source from entity model, then added master table from data source to be as application-form so I choose "**Details**" mode to display one row only.

Then I added the details table as `DataGridView` mode to display all details row linked to the master row.

The problem is the column order is changed in the data source, not as the order in DB table, so the navigation order between columns is changed.

How to change the default **"next item navigation"** between textboxes by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> in master textboxes?

Note: I meant **"details"** with **" "** is display mode in the data source, while details without **" "** means foreign key data.

Comment: You may try to set the TabIndex properties of that text boxes pertinent to the required navigation order. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell , your comment is really helpful, and solve the problem. I checked the property many times without noticing it, I was surprised with 20 views without any answer for this question,  so thank you.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Please mark the question answered if you are satisfied with the solution. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your question, the navigation order between `TextBox` Controls can be defined by setting their `TabIndex` property correspondingly. Best regards,